# Date time object with time zone not working in objective C app development

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cordova

I am having following objective -C code. dateServer , dateClient are showing same value, but actually they should be different, because of which timeDiff is coming null.

```
NSDate *dateClient  = [NSDate date];

[NSTimeZone setDefaultTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"PDT"]];
NSDate *dateServer = [NSDate date];

NSLog(@"dateServer=%@",[dateServer description]);
NSLog(@"dateClient=%@",[dateClient description]);

NSTimeInterval timeDiff = [dateClient timeIntervalSinceDate:dateServer];

NSString *dateStr = @"2012-09-21 05:34:24";

// Convert string to date object
NSDateFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter2 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *dateNew = [formatter2 dateFromString:dateStr];  
NSLog(@"date new %@" , [dateNew description]);
```

At the end, date new is coming something other than the string specified. Why is this happening, i just want to convert string to date.
Can anybody suggest what could be wrong in both the places.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code

```
NSDate* dateClient = [NSDate date];

NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"PDT"];
NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

NSInteger sourceGMTOffset = [sourceTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:dateClient];
NSInteger destinationGMTOffset = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:dateClient];
NSTimeInterval interval = destinationGMTOffset - sourceGMTOffset;
```

[image: NSTimeInterval]

Comment: No.. I have posted the screen shot

Comment: You should explain what you're trying to do here so that the OP can learn what the code does, not just cargo-cult it into his application.

Comment: However i got a minus vote... @JonathanGrynspan Its worked fine to him :) u can remove the down vote now :)

Comment: I still think you should explain the answer for future reference. :)

Answer (score 0):

[NSDate date]; is giving you the current time.
so you are comparing the timeInterval between dateClient and dateServer, wich both carry the current time. that's why timeDiff results zero.